# Powershell -match "Cannot index into a null array"

Tags: regex, xml, string, powershell, pattern-matching

I have an `xml` file, ignore the numbers at the start, that's not part of it.

```
(1)<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
(2)<one>
(3)<x> </x>
(4)</one><look> HERE </look> <find> 123 </find> <some> </some>
(5)<two></two>
```

I **know** there is a line that has a `<look> HERE </look>` tag, and I want to be able to find the value located within the `<find>` tags (in this case `123`), which is on the same line.

```
Get-Content '.\x.xml' # works

$line = $x -match "<look> HERE </look>" # this returns the entire line (line 4 in this case)

$line -match "<find>(?<content>.*)</find>"

$matches['content'] #cannot index into a null array error
```

Why? I expect to get `123` returned

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You appear to be missing the closing quotes in both -match calls.

Comment: Minor mistake from me, but that is no the issue for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try parsing XML this way instead. Powershell can cast strings into XML objects, and [per my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) using regex to parse XML is not a good idea.

```
$x = [xml]@"
<xml>
<one>
<x> </x>
</one><look> HERE </look> <find> 123 </find> <some> </some>
<two></two>
</xml>
"@

$x.xml.find
```

> 123

Comment: This is good, but it requires knowledge of the xml layout itself, and xml's can be pretty big, and so the here string would be too. Thanks for the answer

Comment: The `here-string` in this case is just a replacement for your `get-content` call.  Use `[xml]$x = get-content ...` and you'll have forced it to parse the content as an xml file and get the object back.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the actual question as to why (regardless of if you should be doing it that way.  Jacob Colvin's answer provides a better method.

A single string returns a `boolean` and returns `$true` or `$false` when using `-match`

If instead you use `Select-String` you can then use `ForEach-Object { $_.matches.groups } | Where-Object {$_.name -match 'content'} | select -expand value` to get the information you want.

So the two options would be:

```powershell
$line | Where-Object {
    $_ -match "<find>(?<content>.*)</find>"
} | ForEach-Object {
    $matches['content']
}
# Or
$line | select-string "<find>(?<content>.*)</find>" | ForEach-Object {
    $_.matches.groups
} | Where-Object {
    $_.name -match "content"
} | Select -Expand value
```

Answer (score 2):

When `-match` is applied against a collection, it always returns a collection. If you look at the type of `$line` you'll see that it's array of 1 element:

```
> $line.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
> $line.Count
1
```

When matching against a collection, `$matches` isn't set since there could be multiple matches in the collection. `$matches` is only set for scalar match operations. Since `$line` is still a collection, to make this work you need to index into `$line` before applying `-match`:

```
> $line[0] -match "<find>(?<content>.*)</find>"
True
```

Now the match succeeds for the scalar value and `content` is set:

```
> $matches['content']
 123
```

Comment: Interesting. So are xml's referred to as collections here?

Comment: In this case the `xml` is actually just an array of strings.  If you did `$x.getType()` it should be `[String[]]`.

Comment: OMG thank you for this explanation...this distinction led to quite a subtle bug for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and the solution was just trivial. 
I had to wrap my string with "".

I made a search replace in a file:

```
    $content = (Get-Content filename.txt)
    $content -match '.*(?<namedGroup>test)'
    Write-Output $Matches.namedGroup
```

and I had to change it to :

```
    $content = (Get-Content filename.txt)
    "$content" -match '.*(?<namedGroup>test)'
    Write-Output $Matches.namedGroup
```

Comment: Thank you, Dan, this did the trick for me as well. I don't understand why, though.